# how to create a simple event website, where the events will be sorted by date and fetched from a database?

Tags: php, html, web

I could not find the proper solution. So, could you please provide me a with a sample code for the sorting of contents.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Please answer this as fast as possible!

Comment: Please read the link I gave you. It will help you understand how to use sort in SQL. This should also help you: https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: *Please answer this as fast as possible!* – Whaaaa? The fastest answer is that this question is "This question is off topic."

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date DESC"
```

It seems as though you want a sample code for the full website by the way. :(